# Obtaining user table for one site on multisite set up

Tags: multisite, users, mysql, table

I'm trying to select only users that are registered for a specific site on my multisite set up and see that the table for the users has collected everyone that is on the network. Is there away I can get only the users on a specific site? Or only select the users from that specific site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, all the WordPress Multisite users go into the `{$wpdb->prefix}users` table; that way they form a pool of users that can each be given access to one or more sites in your network.

You can get the users for a given site by using [`get_users()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_users), which can take as an argument the ID of a given site:

```
// get users for site example.com/my-site
$args = array(
    'blog_id' = get_id_from_blogname( 'my-site' ),
);
$users_for_site = get_users( $args );
```

If you're using Multisite, and the `blog_id` argument isn't set, you'll get the users for the current site.

#### Comparing email addresses

By default, `get_users()` returns an array of [`WP_User` objects](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User), so you should be able to compare your list of email addresses (assumed to be contained in the array `$my_user_emails` in the code below) to the list of addresses returned by `get_users()`:

```
// uses $users_for_site from the previous code block

$no_email_entered = array();
foreach( $users_for_site as $user ) {
    if( ! in_array( $user->user_email, $my_user_emails ) ) {
        $no_email_entered[] = $user->user_email;
    }
}
// $no_email_entered should now contain all the email addresses 
// in the list of site users that are *not* in your table
```

#### References

- [`get_users()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_users)
- [`get_id_from_blogname()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_id_from_blogname)
- [`WP_User` class](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User)

Comment: Thanks, how could I compare this information to the data in a separate table? I want to see how many registered users did not input their email into a form I created and made a table for.

Comment: I've updated my answer to cover one way to do this. There are probably more elegant ways to do it, but this should work.